# how to ensure php/html login form does not load values in the username and password fields

Tags: php, html, forms

I have written this simple php code (see below). The problem is that when i try running this code, the form loads values into both the username and password input fields. I have tried setting autocomplete = "off" in both the form tag and the input tag as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag?rq=1) but it does not seem to work. My browser if firefox 38.0 for Ubuntu canonical 1.0. What is the problem here?

```html
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){echo "yesu";
  $username = $_POST['username']; 
  $password = md5 ($_POST['password'] . 'ijdb');
  print "welcome $username";
/*header ('Location: .');
exit();*/

  }
    else{
?>
<form action = "" method = "post" autocomplete = "off">
Username: <input type = "text" name = "username" autocomplete = "off"/><p>
Password: <input type = "password" name = "password" autocomplete = "off"/><p>
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "login"/>
<form>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: sounds like something you have installed in your browser

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2530/4323504

Comment: @Luthando Loot. I have pointed this out in my question by citing the thread with a link. Clearly as you can see,  the autocomplete = off does not work for my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a hidden empty text field between `username` and `password`

```
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="text" style="display:none">// like this 
<input type="password" style="display:none">// Introducing this line ensures that whenever you load the form the password field is blank
<input type="password" name="password">
```

**Explain**

> It will make the username text field not to show any previously typed
>   words in a drop down. Since there is no attribute like name, id for
>   the input field  it wouldn't
>   send any extra parameters also.

Comment: please explain what will that text field do

Comment: thanks for the explanation, i cant really test it though....@Alex, please let me know if this works

Comment: @Saty...your solution works fine for username. How about for password type?

Comment: @saty...yes it is not working for password field but working for username field

Comment: add this line <input type="password" style="display:none">/ after password filed and try

Comment: @saty adding the after password hides the whole input field

Comment: @AlexMaina add in before and try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78868/discussion-between-alex-maina-and-saty).

Comment: @AlexMaina you are welcome !! enjoy also told Luthando loot about this

Answer (score 0):

Use placeholders

```
Username: <input type = "text" name = "username" placeholder = "username"/>
Password: <input type = "password" name = "password" placeholder = "password"/>
```

Comment: i have used them placeholders as suggested but still the form loads values...@Babar

Answer (score 0):

seems like some preset in your browser(check addons or whatever), 
anyway if you wish to get rid of it - just use custom names for inputs, aka:

```
Username: <input type = "text" name = "uname" autocomplete = "off"/>
```

or

```
Username: <input type = "text" name = "something_unusual" autocomplete = "off"/>`
```

Comment: Thanks @Dimas i have tried using custom names but still not getting desired results

Comment: just as extreme measures if nothing else will not help - generate some random UI per form render.

Answer (score 0):

There are three things you can try:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```

Ensure that when you are using `autocomplete="off"` that you an `html5` declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Lastly, it might also be browser settings remembers especially passwords and username combinations